# Accessing members of a Graph data type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, graph, functional-programming, custom-data-type

My question is simple, I'm really new in the world of functional programming so I was wondering how I can access the element of my data type to create an empty graph, for example.

```
module Graph where

import Data.Map (Map)

import Graphviz

-- | A directed graph
data Graph v = Graph
    { arcsMap :: Map v [v]     -- A map associating a vertex with its successors
    , labelMap :: Map v String -- The Graphviz label of each node
    , styleMap :: Map v String -- The Graphviz style of each node
    }

-- | Returns an empty graph
emptyGraph :: Graph v
emptyGraph = ???
```

thankyou!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import Data.Map (Map, empty)

-- | A directed graph
data Graph v = Graph
   { arcsMap :: Map v [v]     -- A map associating a vertex with its successors
   , labelMap :: Map v String -- The Graphviz label of each node
   , styleMap :: Map v String -- The Graphviz style of each node
   }

-- | Returns an empty graph
emptyGraph :: Graph v
emptyGraph = Graph empty empty empty
```

Comment: Ohhh, thanks a lot i didn't know that empty was alredy in Data.Map

Comment: Have a nice day

Comment: @VelyynS: You can also use `mempty` here because `Map` is an instance of `Monoid`—judiciously choosing polymorphic functions like `mempty` over `Data.Map.empty`, or `fmap` over `map`, makes code slightly more resilient to changes in representation, i.e., coding to the interface rather than the implementation

Comment: @VelyynS: And of course you can enumerate the fields explicitly using record notation: `emptyGraph = Graph { arcsMap = mempty, labelMap = mempty, styleMap = mempty }`